# Detect when a appllication is launch in Tizen

Tags: web-applications, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I want to create an application lock for requests from the Tizen platform. I want my application to be called every time when another application (which is to be locked) is launched and it comes in foreground.

Ideas for both native as well as web applications are welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I improved grammar/spelling to make your question easier to digest.  You should also consider showing evidence of approaches you've tried (reference code or tool/frameworks) as you are more likely to receive assistance if you show you've made a significant effort already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use systemd capabilities. You must adjust properly Unit file of your service (specify Wants or WahtedBy and etc.. see systemd man). For ex., systemd can run your service if someone tries to communicate on your service socket!!!

Comment: Could you provide an example for clarity?